# Test against voltage

Tags: digital-logic

What is an easy way to do this? I'm really going in circles and would need an overview:

There is a certain input line, output line, a high voltage, a low voltage - and a reference voltage.

Now if the input is higher than the reference the output will be "high voltage". If the input is lower than the reference the output will be "low voltage". How can this be achieved?

I've only got diodes, transistors, resistors (and capacitors/inductors etc) to do this. If I would use an amplifier I need to build one myself.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Schmitt_trigger_with_transistors.svg The trick is to size the resistors for your required thresholds.

Comment: @jippie, that circuit doesn't have an input for the reference voltage.

Comment: I'd definitely buy a comparator but if you want to make one your self take a look at the [long tail pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-tail_pair#Long-tailed_pair). By giving this a lot of gain (Making RE big, or replacing it with a constant current sink) you can make the voltage at the output switch. Then use that to switch another transistor

Comment: @ThePhoton R1/R2 and Rc1 define the thresholds. Indeed, it is a fixed voltage.

Comment: @clabacchio, Okay, I made an answer. But I think there's still room for a better answer if someone would like to do the work to give a schematic that allows for logic level output swing and fast response.

Comment: @ThePhoton you're right, but I think that he just needs to be pointed out in the right direction, than he can sort out the details himself ;)

Answer (score 2):

The function you are looking for is called a *comparator*.

Unfortunately, you'll find out it's much easier to design a good comparator in an IC than build one from discretes. IC comparators are available for $0.50 each. It may be an interesting academic excercise to build one, but the engineering solution should be to buy it.

If you still want to build one from discretes, the typical circuit is called a [long-tail pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-tail_pair#Long-tailed_pair). For a comparator you would choose the component values in this circuit to give very high gain, or probably even add a second amplifier stage, so that even small differences in the inputs cause the output to swing full-scale. On the other hand you also might want to limit the saturation currents through the transistors so that the circuit can respond quickly when the input changes.